# berkeley socket programming issues - <netinet.h> not found

Tags: networking, io, sockets, socks5

My standard socket stuff doesnt work anymore on Ubuntu 20.04.4 - <netinet.h> not found. This then leads to definition errors of sockaddr.

```
s.c:22:14: error: ‘struct sockaddr’ has no member named ‘sin_family’; did you mean ‘sa_family’?
   22 |   serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~
      |              sa_family
```

e.g.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  int sockfd, clientfd;
  struct sockaddr serverAddr, cliAddr;
  socklen_t addr_size;
  int len = sizeof(cliAddr);
  char serverMessage[256] = "Hello from server\n";

  sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  
  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(9002); 
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

  // listen 
  if(listen(sockfd,5)==0)
  clientfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliAddr, &len);

  send(clientfd,serverMessage,sizeof(serverMessage),0);
  close(sockfd);
  return 0;
}
```

(taken from https://www.prodevelopertutorial.com/linux-system-programming-creating-tcp-sockets/)

But really any standard berkeley socket code will do.
This seems like a pretty catastrophic issue.

How do I replace netinet.h on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: The page you linked appears to include `<netinet/in.h>` rather than `<netinet.h>` - perhaps that is significant?

Comment: @steeldriver it is.  Feel free to answer ;-)

Comment: tried that, but I get the same errors:


error: ‘struct sockaddr’ has no member named ‘sin_family’; did you mean ‘sa_family’?
error: ‘struct sockaddr’ has no member named ‘sin_port’
error: ‘struct sockaddr’ has no member named ‘sin_addr’

Comment: it works if i use `<netinet/in.h>` and change `sockaddr` to `sockaddr_in` ... but that breaks all of my code.